# vuejs lifecycle hooks mounted push computed

Tags: vuejs3

I want to send the data from axios in `mounted` to the `menuItem` function in `computed`, but I have not been successful. Where am I doing wrong?

```html
<template v-slot:MenuItem>
  <MenuItems
    v-for="(Item, Index) in menuItem"
    :key="Index"
    :items="Item"
    :depth="Index"
  >
    <router-link :to="Item.path">{{ Item.name }}</router-link>
  </MenuItems>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Nav',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    menuItem() {
      return [
        {
          name: this.$t('navbar.home'),
          path: '/',
        },
        {
          name: this.$t('navbar.gallery'),
          path: '/gallery',
        },
        {
          name: this.$t('navbar.contact'),
          path: '/contact',
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/categories')
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const arr = res.data.data
      arr.forEach((value, index) => {
        this.menuItem.push({
          name: value.title,
          path: '/' + value.slug,
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working so far? Did you checked the Vue devtools to debug the actual state there?

Comment: Oh wait, you're trying to push to a computed. I'm not sure that you can do that without a [writable computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed).

Comment: so how can i do it? Can you help